# iOS change price when submitting new version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm submitting a new version of my app and I want to make it paying (it wasn't before), and I can't find where I can plan a change when the app is ready for sale. Please can someone tell me where it is, I didn't found on internet.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know, if the "price update on app update" mechanism exists (it's not that it doesn't exist, I just don't know). But you could set the release to manual and then release the app/update the price simultaneously, or you could schedule the release date (release not earlier than...) and schedule the price change as well. However the later scenario is not 100% reliable, since if the review takes longer, the price will be updated anyway.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pricing schedule in Pricing And Availability

[image]